# Missing harmonics (power-line)

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency

I have some biomedical signals. If I calculate their magnitude spectrums, I see power-line interference at 50 Hz. I was excepting a harmonic at 100 Hz, but it turns out there is none. However, there is a harmonic at 150 Hz. Is this common or should I worry that I have done something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your frequency scaling in Fourier domain was right?

Comment: Yes I think so. There's also harmonic at 250 Hz, but not 200 Hz.

Comment: If you are confident that you have scaled your frequency axis correctly, then what you see is what you get.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/AC_10.html

I see in the page that you can miss a few harmonics. Just went through it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is common. Common non-linearities (such as op-amp clipping) preserve the symmetry of the upper and lower section of the waveform; and as such, they do not introduce even harmonics - just odd harmonics.

Comment: non-linearities with odd symmetry produce odd harmonics, and even symmetry produce even harmonics (for sine wave input)